# White pixels at left border in gnome flashback

Tags: 14.04, display, gnome-classic, metacity

I run the Gnome Flashback with Metacity session.  I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.1.  After the upgrade, when I have an application maximized, there sometimes appears a little 1-pixel-wide white column at the left edge of the screen.

[image: illustration]

<sup>(Black border added for visibility)</sup>

which can be erased by causing the application to draw over it.  For instance, if I select a line in the pictured terminal, or if I click the "File" menu button, the white pixels will go away where they were overwritten.  However, if for instance I switch to another maximized window and back, the white pixels will reappear.  This issue manifests itself not only in the terminal but in all maximized applications.  How can I get rid of these?

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading to newer Ubuntu version. This problem is fixed in Metacity 3.12.0, but it is available only in Ubuntu 14.10.